# Javascript, IndexedDB, storing Uint8Array, Giving Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, indexeddb, uint8array

It's been a few hours since I began reading about IndexedDB and I am having some issues. This is code I followed from https://medium.com/@AndyHaskell2013/build-a-basic-web-app-with-indexeddb-8ab4f83f8bda and https://gist.github.com/JamesMessinger/a0d6389a5d0e3a24814b and it's just put together poorly for comprehension's sake. So what I am trying to do is store a secret key into IndexedDB so that I can use it to encrypt things with the ECIES scheme.

Relevant code (sequential order):

```
var secretKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();

window.genSKey = function()
{
 openDB();
 console.log(secretKey);
 return;
}
```

```
window.openDB = function()
{
let db;
let dbReq = indexedDB.open('ln', 1);
dbReq.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  // Set the db variable to our database so we can use it!  
  db = event.target.result;

  // Create an object store named notes. Object stores
  // in databases are where data are stored.
  let skey = db.createObjectStore('skey', {keyPath: "id"});
}
dbReq.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = event.target.result;

  setSkey(db);
  getSkey(db);

}
dbReq.onerror = function(event) {
  alert('error opening database ' + event.target.errorCode);
}
}

window.setSkey = function(db) {
    // Start a database transaction and get the notes object store
    let tx = db.transaction(['skey'], 'readwrite');
    let store = tx.objectStore('skey');
    // Put the sticky note into the object store
    store.put({id: 1, secretKey});
    // Wait for the database transaction to complete
    tx.oncomplete = function() { console.log('private key was saved') }
    tx.onerror = function(event) {
      alert('error storing private key ' + event.target.errorCode);
    }
  }

  window.getSkey = function(db)
  {
      // Set up an object store and transaction
let tx = db.transaction(['skey'], 'readonly');
let store = tx.objectStore('skey');
// Set up a request to get the sticky note with the key 1
let req = store.get(1);
// We can use the note if the request succeeds, getting it in the
// onsuccess handler
req.onsuccess = function(event) {
  let skey = event.target.result;
  if (skey) {
    console.log(skey);
  } else {
    console.log("skey 1 not found")
  }
}
// If we get an error, like that the note wasn't in the object
// store, we handle the error in the onerror handler
req.onerror = function(event) {
  alert('error getting note 1 ' + event.target.errorCode);
}
```

for some reason when genSKey is called in front end scripting, I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
    at window.setSkey (http://127.0.0.1:5500/browserify/builds/genKey.js:26763:17)
    at IDBOpenDBRequest.dbReq.onsuccess (http://127.0.0.1:5500/browserify/builds/genKey.js:26752:3)
window.setSkey @ genKey.js:26763
dbReq.onsuccess @ genKey.js:26752
IndexedDB (async)
window.openDB @ genKey.js:26740
window.genSKey @ genKey.js:26601
signupData @ signup.html:186
onclick @ signup.html:64
```

the console logs more things but the other things have nothing to do with the issue at hand. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and I have been at it all day. Some insight will mean the world to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably created the database without the object store. to trigger `onupgradeneeded` which will go and create the object store you have to connect to the database with a higher version number.

Comment: so, just to make sure we're on the same page ```let dbReq = indexedDB.open("ln", 1);``` the second argument needs to be a higher number and then it will work? And the object store was created in "setSkey()" Which gets called into "openDB()'s" onsuccess function.

Comment: it will work ... once. you're going to have to revise onupgradeneeded so it can react to whatever is the last version and the new version. yes you have to create the object store so that when you query against it, you do not not get an object-store-not-found kind of error.

Comment: you are a profit, can you please explain to me why changing the db version gets this result? And how I can automate this.

Comment: increasing the version number causes indexedDb to run onupgradeneeded when the version number changes. if it never changes it never runs. you probably created the database without this function existing, then never incremented version. to automate, write the onupgradeneeded function and then when the schema changes use a new version.